# ROUNDING based on digits of number

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
         A                 B           
1        6.355            6.000     
2       58.690           50.000
3      357.867          350.000
4    1.260.563        1.200.000
5   12.480.370       12.400.000
```

In **Column A** I have a bunch of radnom numbers that can change everytime the user enters new data into the spreadsheet.

In **Column B** I want to CUT and ROUNDDOWN the numbers in **Column A** in the following systematic:

```
Number consists of 4 digits  -->  CUT and ROUNDDOWN after the 1st digit
Number consitst of 5 digits  -->  CUT and ROUNDDOWN after the 1st digit
Number consists of 6 digits  -->  CUT and ROUNDDOWN after the 2nd digit
Number consists of 7 digits  -->  CUT and ROUNDDOWN after the 2nd digit
Number consists of 8 digits  -->  CUT and ROUNDDOWN after the 3rd digit
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,1-LEN(A1))
```

However, this formular only works well for the 4-5 digits numbers. Afterwards I would have to change the **1** to a **2** and so on.

Is there a way to do this rounding automatically based on the systematic described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following formula in `B1` downwards:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,-(INT(LOG10(A1)/2)+2))
```